# jQuery Javascript to validate Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This [tutorial](http://www.sweetsindesign.com/web/customizing-google-form-confirmation-page) produces this [signup form](http://www.sweetsindesign.com/codes/google-form/index.html) to validate the email field and to display a custom confirmation message instead of the default message by Google Form.

I want to copy the tutorial, but I am NOT getting the same result.

On that signup form page, I right-clicked and hit "view source". I copied the source code and pasted into an empty index.php of my wordpress site, but I don't get the same result. The email field should turn red if the field is not filled out, but my signup form does not produce a red field.

How can I have different result if I am literally copying the same exact code from "view source"? Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there more code that is not displayed in the "view source" code?

**EDIT**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#emailSubscription").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore",
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $('#emailSubscription').toggle();
      form.submit();
      $('.hidden-message').show();
    }
  });
  
  var submitted = false;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  color: #3d5e60;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
}
.my-google-form {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #61787a;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EFEFEF 0%, #BABABA 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #EFEFEF), color-stop(100%, #BABABA));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #EFEFEF 0%, #BABABA 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #EFEFEF 0%, #BABABA 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #EFEFEF 0%, #BABABA 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EFEFEF 0%, #BABABA 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#EFEFEF', endColorstr='#BABABA', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
input {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.input-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.input-wrapper input.ss-q-short {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.submit-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #EFEFEF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #61787a;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #61787a 0%, #3d5e60 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #61787a), color-stop(100%, #3d5e60));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #61787a 0%, #3d5e60 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #61787a 0%, #3d5e60 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #61787a 0%, #3d5e60 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #61787a 0%, #3d5e60 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#61787a', endColorstr='#3d5e60', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  border: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input-wrapper input.error {
  border: 1px solid #990000;
  background: #ffcccc;
  color: #990000;
}
.input-wrapper label.error {
  display: block;
  color: #990000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-wrapper .error-message {
  display: none;
}
.hidden-message {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="my-google-form">
  <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MoRmfek0fJjT1THfKWZqhmAt3YaCXvMML7CLhGbg7fc/formResponse" method="POST" id="emailSubscription" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
    <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
      <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
        <div class="ss-form-entry">
          <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_251567901">
            <h1 class="ss-q-title">Subscribe to our newsletter</h1> 
            <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
          </label>
          <div class="ss-item ss-navigate input-wrapper">
            <input placeholder="Name is not necessary but nice" type="text" name="entry.1542678317" value="" class="ignore ss-q-short" id="entry_1542678317" dir="auto" aria-label="Name  " title="">
            <input placeholder="Enter your email address" type="email" name="entry.251567901" value="" class="ss-q-short required" id="entry_251567901" dir="auto" aria-label="subscribe to our newsletter  Must be a valid email address" aria-required="true"
            required title="Must be a valid email address" aria-invalid="true">
            <input type="Submit" name="ss-submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit" class="submit-button">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="draftResponse" value="[,,&quot;-8281247560927290473&quot;]
">
    <input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="fbzx" value="-8281247560927290473">
  </form>
  <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) {}"></iframe>
  <div class="hidden-message" style="display: none;">Thanks! Look out for our weekly newsletter.
    <br /> <small> View your response <a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r0bEV5sTlY7PQWLREE0W5Chuy6LSkrPtVCBEHmHzMhI/edit?usp=sharing" target="_blank">here.</a> </small> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without code or error messages or anything of the sort its really impossible to divine what the issue might be.

Comment: You likely left out the CSS.

Comment: you might have forgot to get required `css` and `js` files

Comment: please see the hyperlinks in my original post "tutorial" and "signup form" the view source code contains the css and js

Comment: Like @Craicerjack mentioned it's difficult to debug without anymore info. But for email newsletters in WordPress I use https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/ It's an WordPress plugin for mailchimp, which I use to handle emails

Comment: please provide some code of index.php file

Comment: @leko Hyperlinks are all well and good, however hyperlinks can break. You should **always** post your code in your question.

Comment: please see my edit for the entire code

Comment: Did you download the jquery.validate.js file also?

Comment: oh god i'm missing the jquery.validate.js file thanks for your help Juhana and Archangel ...I shall proceed to bang my head on the wall now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two possible reasons you didn't get the same result.

#### First : HTML

With HTML you can include scripts (.js) like that :

```
<script src="some/local/path/to/my/script/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="//example.com/path/to/remote/script/file.js"></script>
```

but also stylesheets (.css) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some/local/path/to/my/stylesheet/file.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//example.com/path/to/remote/stylesheet/file.css">
```

The specify path can be an URL or a local path.
If the tutoral site used local paths to include scripts, the targetted scripts are **locally** stored on the **their site**.

So when you copy paste the sources your server might try to fetch the local resources on your computer but cannot as they are on the tutorial site.

#### Second : AJAX (Javascript)

In JavaScript you can make AJAX requests to the server to dynamically fetch some data. It could be, inter alia, some Javascript scripts or some HTML content.

Comment: oh god i'm missing the jquery.validate.js file thanks for your help Juhana and Archangel ...I shall proceed to bang my head on the wall now....

Comment: Hmm is the first block of code in my Edit of my Original Post actually the jquery.validate.js file or something else?

Comment: No I think not, you can see the jquery.validate.js content by open the sources and click on the "jquery.validate.js" of the <script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> tag.

Comment: bingo! YES I used http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js and it works now!! THANK YOU for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using html5 tag,

for email field:

```
  <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
```

And you can try this also:

```
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/
```